# Count occurrence of an integer and using a case statement in a stored procedure (Server version 8.0.23)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to input a varchar in the call statement and
get the following result

| c | count(*) | d | e | f | g |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lorry | 5 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I have the following tables

```
create table h(
g int,
d int
);

create table i(
c varchar(16) primary key,
e int
);

create table j(
f int,
k datetime
);
```

Data for table h

| g | d |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 8 | 2 |
| 19 | 11 |

I've excluded code from 9-18 to save space.

data for table i

| c | e |
| --- | --- |
| Lorry | 1 |
| Norris | 2 |
| Rory | 11 |

I've excluded code from 3-10 to save space.

data for table j

| f | k |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2003-02-05 13:28:57 |
| 2 | 2003-02-06 21:30:57 |
| 19 | 2019-03-07 11:36:31 |

I've excluded code from 3-18 to save space.

I have written the following code

```
drop procedure if exists a;
delimiter //
create procedure a(b varchar(20)) 
begin
select c, count(*), d, e, f, g, 
case
when d < 1 then 'still'
when d between 1 and 2 then 'slow'
when d between 3 and 5 then 'intermediate'
when d > 5 then 'fast'
where c = b
group by c
end as a
from h join i on e = d join j on f = g;
end //
delimiter ;
call a('Lorry');
```

I'm getting

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
> to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
> 'from h join i on e = d join j on f = g wher'

I wonder how to resolve this error.

Comment: the sql code cited in the error is not matching what you posted. can you please post the tables with real names?

Comment: Sry, I've updated it with the right names now @Lelio Faieta

Comment: You put `where c = b group by c` into CASE body... it must be placed after `from..join..`.

Comment: Ok, so `end as a` should come after  `when d > 5 then 'fast'` ?

Comment: What are the value of  h, i and j?

Answer (score 1):

I moved WHERE and GROUP BY clauses at the end. You have to add the rest of the columns in the GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT c, count(*), d, e, f, g, 
  CASE
    WHEN d < 1 THEN 'still'
    WHEN d BETWEEN 1 and 2 THEN 'slow'
    WHEN d BETWEEN 3 and 5 THEN 'intermediate'
    WHEN d > 5 THEN 'fast'
  END as a
FROM h 
JOIN i ON e = d 
JOIN j ON f = g
WHERE c = b
GROUP BY c, d, e, f, g
```

Answer (score 0):

Here goes a workable version of your code but I am not sure if it's generating your desired result without the data of h, i and j and your desired output:

> ```
> create table h(
> g int,
> d int
> );
>
> create table i(
> c varchar(16) primary key,
> e int
> );
>
> create table j(
> f int,
> k datetime
> );
> ```

> ```
> insert into h values(1    ,1);
> insert into h values(2    ,1);
> insert into h values(3    ,1);
> insert into h values(4    ,1);
> insert into h values(5    ,1);
> insert into h values(6    ,1);
> insert into h values(7    ,2);
> insert into h values(8    ,2);
> insert into h values(19   ,11);
> ```

> ```
> insert into i values('Lorry', 1);
> insert into i values('Norris',    2);
> insert into i values('Rory',  11);
> ```

> ```
> insert into j values(1,   '2003-02-05 13:28:57');
> insert into j values(2,   '2003-02-06 21:30:57');
> insert into j values(19,  '2019-03-07 11:36:31');
> ```

> ```
> create procedure a(b varchar(20)) 
> begin
>
>  select c, count(*), d, e, f, g, 
>  case
>      when d < 1 then 'still'
>      when d between 1 and 2 then 'slow'
>      when d between 3 and 5 then 'intermediate'
>      when d > 5 then 'fast' end as a
>
>  from h join i 
>                on e = d join j on f = g
>  where c = b
>  group by c,d,e,f,g;
>
> end;
> ```

> ```
> Call a('Lorry')
> ```

> | c | count(*) | d | e | f | g | a |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Lorry | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | slow |
> | Lorry | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | slow |
>
> ✓

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7c8218aca6dfee97727939f1a4918a04)*

Comment: Thank you @Kazi Mohammad Ali Nur. I've updated with the data for table h, i and j.

Comment: No, unfortunately I get "Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; ..right syntax to use near '' at line 12"

Comment: your mysql version?

Comment: Please check the revised answer.